# Python Regular Expression : Extracting string within a word

Tags: python-2.7

Can you please show how to extract 'abc.txt.gz' from below:

'      Successfully downloaded abc.txt.gz '

Note: 
- the name 'abc' will vary
- there is no space between 'abc.txt.gz' and '

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Comment: Please show you have tried something yourself by giving us a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## split

You could just [`split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) around whitespaces, and get the last element :

```
'Successfully downloaded abc.txt.gz'.split(' ')[-1]
```

It outputs :

```
'abc.txt.gz'
```

## rsplit

@jonrsharpe mentioned in the comments that [`rsplit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit):

```
'Successfully downloaded abc.txt.gz'.rsplit(' ',1)[-1]
```

would be more efficient.

## regex

If you really want to use a Regexp :

```
import re
txt_gz = re.compile(r'\S+\.txt\.gz\b')

match = txt_gz.search('Successfully downloaded abc.txt.gz')
if match:
    print match.group(0)
else:
    print "Not found"
```

Comment: An `rsplit` might be more efficient

Comment: @JRodDynamite: Why would you introduce a `SyntaxError` to my code?

Comment: @EricDuminil - How so? I simply formatted your answer to a Python shell based input-output.

Comment: Yep, that's the idea. Also that's not a syntax error, just making it look like the standard interpreter session.

Comment: @JRodDynamite: Doing so, you also make it harder to copy-paste the code IMHO. A total Python beginner might be puzzled by the SyntaxError.

Comment: Looking at previously accepted Python answers, it doesn't seem usual to write code as in a REPL.

Comment: @EricDuminil - Agree. But since this was a simple one-line answer and you were also showing an output, I thought of showing it in REPL. :)

Comment: I understand. Sorry for the harsh comment.